# How can I change component local state using parameters?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I am having some issues trying to change the local state of a component using parameters.

This is the code I have:

```
class App extends Component {
  state = {
    startup: '',
    investor: '',
    realState: '',
    ecoProject: '',
  };

  handleChangeCardSelection = async (e, stateValue, otherCards) => {
    const currentCard = await e.currentTarget.id;

    this.setState({
      [stateValue]: currentCard,
      [otherCards]: '',
    });
  };

  render() {

   const { startup, investor, realState, ecoProject } = this.state;

   return(
     <Card
        id="investor"                  
        onClick={e => this.handleChangeCardSelection(e, [investor])} />
   )
  }
}
```

So, basically I don't want to create a new function for every item in the state.

All I want is to call `this.handleChangeCardSelection` function and then set the value of the item I want, and set empty strings for the other values in the state.

Like in the case of the code above, I need to do something like:

```
this.setState({
    investor: 'investor' // or any other value to fill the string
    startup: '',
    realState: '',
    ecoProject: '',
  })
```

And right now what I am getting from the function I am calling on click, is this state:

```
"": "investor"
ecoProject: ""
investor: ""
realState: ""
startup: ""
undefined: ""
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

Change `[investor]` to `investor`

```
onClick={e => this.handleChangeCardSelection(e, investor)} />
```

Answer (score 0):

You aren't passing the parameter to the function correctly. You don't need to wrap parameter within `[]` while passing to function

```
<Card
    id="investor"                  
    onClick={e => this.handleChangeCardSelection(e, investor)} />
```